# Is it possible to populate the 'FROM' field with a default email address when sending emails from cases records in salesforce?

Tags: email, case

When sending an email from a case the 'FROM' field is populated with the user email address.
Is it possible to populate the 'FROM' field with a default email address when sending emails from cases records in Salesforce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to do it. You need to create custom button and pass the default email value in the URL. You may look into this.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006tqzAAA

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any other approach? like overriding and creating a custom controller for that button?

Comment: Ron, You could create a custom controller, but in the end, it would need to send you to the same page with the same parameters, so it may not be worth the effort. On a side note, I have found that some of the parameter requirements have changed in Winter'16, and since Salesforce does not official support use of the link, I can't find where they documented it. One of the changes has to do with the From field (p26) - It now needs to specify both the Name and Email address separated by a ':' and the other is that the p3_lkid (recipient) needs to be limited to 15 characters if you use email-2-case

Comment: Hi,  Thank you. 
So I would need to create a custom button and replace it with the one displayed in the Activities related list on each Case object page layout ?
And for p26, When I send the email it is ok, it does not identify the colon.